# Update column with alphabetical list from a different select statement

Tags: mysql

I am looking to do a SQL update statement that seems to have some complexities.

I have an inventory table of cars, and it looks like this:

Inventory

| CarID | Car | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ford | Blue |
| 2 | Ford | Red |
| 3 | Ford | Green |
| 4 | Chevy | Blue |
| 5 | Chevy | Black |
| 6 | Chevy | White |

I am trying to UPDATE a summary table that looks like this (the update statement will run whenever the Inventory table gets updated):

Summary

| CarSummaryID | Car | Colors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ford | Blue, Green, Red |
| 2 | Chevy | Black, Blue, White |

How do I write an Update statement which will popular the Summary table for each car with the corresponding colors and put the colors in alphabetical order?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add a UNIQUE KEY to `Summary.Car`, you can use [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) this way:

```
INSERT INTO Summary (Car, Colors)
SELECT Car, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Color ORDER BY Color) AS Colors
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY Car
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Colors = VALUES(Colors);
```

Or on MySQL 8.0:

```
INSERT INTO Summary (Car, Colors)
SELECT Car, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Color ORDER BY Color) AS NewColors
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY Car
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Colors = NewColors;
```

If you can't make the UNIQUE KEY, then IODKU won't work. It only updates rows if there's a unique key conflict with an existing row.

In that case, use a multi-table UPDATE:

```
UPDATE Summary JOIN (
  SELECT Car, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Color ORDER BY Color) AS NewColors
  FROM Inventory
  GROUP BY Car
) AS t USING (Car)
SET Summary.Colors = t.NewColors;
```

But that will only update existing rows in the `Summary` table, it can't create new rows.

---

If you want it to happen automatically as data changes in `Inventory`, the comment from blabla_bingo is a good one. A trigger would help do that. I haven't tested the following, but something like this may get you started:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InvSummaryIns AFTER INSERT ON Inventory
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO Summary (Car, Colors)
    SELECT Car, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Color ORDER BY Color) AS NewColors
    FROM Inventory
    WHERE Car = NEW.Car
    GROUP BY Car
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Colors = NewColors;
```

The `WHERE` clause is because you would only need to update the row for the respective Car value, not the whole table of all car types.

You would also need similar triggers `AFTER UPDATE` and `AFTER DELETE`, because those also change the inventories.

Comment: That's a decent answer covering duplicate key circumstances. Since the OP says `the update statement will run whenever the Inventory table gets updated`, may I suggest using a trigger ?

Comment: I made an edit to show an ad hoc trigger example (not tested). Also added `DISTINCT` in the GROUP_CONCAT() examples, otherwise you'll see long lists of duplicate color names as your inventory grows.